# converting a Texture2d circle to Farseer circleBody

Tags: c#, xna, texture2d, farseer

I may have asked a similar question before, but believe me, I have searched a lot on the web. I am very new to farseer and xna , and all I want to do is convert existing set of texture2d circles to farseer circleBody? Is there a way to do that without much modification to the existing code?

Comment: What is a "Texture2D circle"? Can you post an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do, is create your Farseer object, and then use its position in your world space to draw a texture on top of it.

Keep in mind that Farseer doesn't handle draw code for your Textures, you need to do this yourself.

Example draw code:

```
batch.Draw(Body.Texture, ConvertUnits.ToDisplayUnits(Body.Position), null, Color.White, Body.Rotation, Body.Origin, 1f, SpriteEffects.None, 0f);
```